# Can ogr2ogr read .kmz files? How?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, file-formats, kmz

Attempting a run-of-the-mill `ogr2ogr` process with a KMZ file failed:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `Rail.kmz' with the following drivers.
```

Is there a trick? (Obvious workaround is to unzip the .kmz first, but that's sometimes clunky, and you don't know what the internal structure will be exactly.)

GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16

Answer (score 7):

GDAL has two drivers for KML, "KML" http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html and "LIBKML" http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html. The LIBKML driver can read KMZ files out-of-the-box. This works for me with the GDAL 2.1-dev version from gisinternals.com:

Acquire test data from https://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/

Run ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo time-stamp-point.kmz -al -so
INFO: Open of "time-stamp-point.kmz"
      using driver `LIBKML' successful.

Layer name: time-stamp-point
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 361
Extent: (-122.556706, 37.848038) - (-122.536226, 37.860470)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Name: String (0.0)
description: String (0.0)
timestamp: DateTime (0.0)
begin: DateTime (0.0)
end: DateTime (0.0)
altitudeMode: String (0.0)
tessellate: Integer (0.0)
extrude: Integer (0.0)
visibility: Integer (0.0)
drawOrder: Integer (0.0)
icon: String (0.0)
```

The KML driver can't rean zipped KML files directly but there is an easy workaround by using the GDAL vsizip-system https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/ReadInZip.

Test with KML driver (notice how to skip the default LIBKML driver if both drivers are installed):

```
ogrinfo /vsizip/time-stamp-point.kmz -al -so --config ogr_skip libkml
ERROR 1: Random access not supported for /vsizip
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `/vsizip/time-stamp-point.kmz'
      using driver `KML' successful.

Layer name: TimeStamp'ed Points
Geometry: 3D Point
Feature Count: 361
Extent: (-122.556706, 37.848038) - (-122.536226, 37.860470)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Name: String (0.0)
Description: String (0.0)
```

Notice also that KML driver finds far less attributes from the data so I would recommend to get a GDAL that has LIBKML driver.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [LibKML](http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html) driver instead of the older [KML](http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html) one. This requires GDAL to be built with [libkml](https://github.com/google/libkml) support.

It sounds like the GDAL binaries you have don't have this support built in; according to the docs:

> Note that if you build and include this LIBKML driver, it will become the default reader of KML for ogr ...

You will either need to rebuild GDAL or find a build with that support.

Or just unzip your KMZs and use the KML driver.