# Cannot access LibKML driver using OGR in Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, libkml

I am trying to read a kmz file using OGR in Python. I believe the standard driver for reading .kmz files is LibKML ([Can ogr2ogr read .kmz files? How?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165310/can-ogr2ogr-read-kmz-files-how)), but I am only getting None when I am building the driver:

```py
import ogr

in_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('LIBKML')

print(in_driver)
None
```

Other drivers I tested work as expected:

```py
in_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
print(in_driver)
<osgeo.ogr.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDriverShadow *' at 0x0000018E73FBCC00> >

in_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Esri Shapefile')
print(in_driver)
<osgeo.ogr.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDriverShadow *' at 0x0000018E73FBCC90> >

in_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('NetCDF')
print(in_driver)
<osgeo.ogr.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDriverShadow *' at 0x0000018E73FBCBA0> >
```

SOME BACKGROUND:

I installed GDAL, which includes OGR, using the conda command. LibKML is one of the dependencies that gets installed with GDAL.

```
(test_env) C:\>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\test_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
altair                    3.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 0.11.1          py37_vc14h261ab4c_1000    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py37_1003    conda-forge
atomicwrites              1.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bcrypt                    3.1.6            py37hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
blosc                     1.16.3               h6538335_1    conda-forge
bokeh                     1.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.68.0            h6a4c333_1000    conda-forge
branca                    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.7             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.15.0            h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.430             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
cftime                    1.0.3.4         py37h452e1ab_1001    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              2.7              py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.65.1               h4496350_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
double-conversion         3.1.5                h6538335_1    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
ephem                     3.7.6.0         py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             habb2df7_1003    conda-forge
folium                    0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h5db478b_0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             hd288d7e_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      3.0.1            py37he6b6c38_2    conda-forge
geos                      3.7.2                habb2df7_1    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.5.1                h8f84788_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hb01d8f6_1002    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            hc0c2ac7_1001    conda-forge
glog                      0.3.5                h6538335_1
grpc-cpp                  1.22.0               h4d7d3fa_0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hf8e6fe8_1002    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_hcc15c50_1100    conda-forge
huracan                   0+untagged.310.gd65af62.dirty           dev_0    <develop>
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.1                     vc14_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.8                   py37_1000    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        0.18                     py37_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
ipykernel                 5.1.1            py37h39e3cac_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.6.1            py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.14.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
joblib                    0.13.2                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                1.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.10            hf7dc31f_1005    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.3            hdd46e55_1001    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.65.1               h4496350_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             h6538335_1006    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.0.1                h73c0052_2    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1005    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h4fd0f3b_1009    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.2             ha953453_1002    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libpq                     11.4                 hb0bdaea_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.8.0                h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16            h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            h832c139_1029    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                h642c060_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h6512ee2_1003    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h9ce36c8_1    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37hed17590_1    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
m2w64-bwidget             1.9.10                        2
m2w64-bzip2               1.0.6                         6
m2w64-expat               2.1.1                         2
m2w64-fftw                3.3.4                         6
m2w64-flac                1.3.1                         3
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gettext             0.19.7                        2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-gsl                 2.1                           2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libjpeg-turbo       1.4.2                         3
m2w64-libogg              1.3.2                         3
m2w64-libpng              1.6.21                        2
m2w64-libsndfile          1.0.26                        2
m2w64-libtiff             4.0.6                         2
m2w64-libvorbis           1.3.5                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-libxml2             2.9.3                         4
m2w64-mpfr                3.1.4                         4
m2w64-openblas            0.2.19                        1
m2w64-pcre                8.38                          2
m2w64-speex               1.2rc2                        3
m2w64-speexdsp            1.2rc3                        3
m2w64-tcl                 8.6.5                         3
m2w64-tk                  8.6.5                         3
m2w64-tktable             2.10                          5
m2w64-wineditline         2.101                         5
m2w64-xz                  5.2.2                         2
m2w64-zlib                1.2.8                        10
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.1.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.1            py37h2852a4a_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0    conda-forge
more-itertools            7.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
netcdf4                   1.5.1.2          py37h8c66456_1    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.8                    py37_1    conda-forge
numba                     0.44.1           py37hf9181ef_0
numexpr                   2.6.9           py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.4           py37hc71023c_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.1                ha922770_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
owslib                    0.18.0                     py_0    conda-forge
packaging                 19.0                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.24.2           py37he350917_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.3                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
paramiko                  2.6.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         2    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.41              h6538335_1003    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pillow                    6.1.0            py37h9a613e6_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
plotly                    3.10.0                     py_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    0.12.0                     py_0    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               heddaa77_6    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
postgresql                11.4                 h06f7779_1    conda-forge
proj4                     6.1.0                hc2d0af5_2    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
pvlib-python              0.6.3                      py_0    conda-forge
py                        1.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   0.11.1          py37h8c67754_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_1    conda-forge
pycrs                     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pynacl                    1.3.0            py37h62dcd97_0
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    2.2.1            py37h3f740ce_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.15.3           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h26f9782_1    conda-forge
pytest                    5.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                h510b542_1    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.0.2           py37he7828b0_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7                hc6833c9_1    conda-forge
r-assertthat              0.2.1            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-backports               1.1.4            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-base                    3.5.1             hdf77c54_1008    conda-forge
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r351h6115d3f_1002    conda-forge
r-cli                     1.1.0            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.3.4           r351h6115d3f_1001    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.20           r351h796a38f_0    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.2.0.1          r351hda5aaf8_0    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.14              r35h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-fansi                   0.4.0           r351h6115d3f_1000    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.3.1            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.3.6           r351hca4a3dc_1002    conda-forge
r-irdisplay               0.7                   r351_1000    conda-forge
r-irkernel                1.0.1            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.6             r351h6115d3f_1000    conda-forge
r-pbdzmq                  0.3_3           r351h9c2a3b9_1001    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.4.2                h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-rcpp                    1.0.1            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-repr                    1.0.1            r351h6115d3f_0    conda-forge
r-rlang                   0.4.0             r35hda5aaf8_0    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.1.4           r351h6115d3f_1000    conda-forge
r-uuid                    0.1_2           r351h6115d3f_1001    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.2.0            r351hda5aaf8_0    conda-forge
r-zeallot                 0.1.0           r351h6115d3f_1000    conda-forge
re2                       2019.07.01       vc14h6538335_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
retrying                  1.3.3                      py_2    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h7208079_1    conda-forge
scipy                     1.2.0            py37h29ff71c_0
seaborn                   0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4           py37ha35856d_1006    conda-forge
simplekml                 1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8          py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7             h6538335_1002    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.28.0               hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.10.0           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2018.0.5             he980bc4_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
thrift-cpp                0.12.0            h59828bf_1002    conda-forge
tiledb                    1.5.1            vc14h30b6f50_2  [vc14]  conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
toolz                     0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
tzwhere                   3.0.3                    py37_0    huracan
uriparser                 0.9.3                he025d50_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.24.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vincent                   0.4.4                      py_1    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             hb1a71c1_1002    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7             hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.1             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
zipp                      0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1004    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                hd8a0e53_0    conda-forge
```

I know that the LIBKML driver must be compiled against the latest version of LibKML (*not* version 1.2) (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/LibKML). I checked my version with conda list, and confirmed the I have LibKML 1.3.0 installed, which I believe is the latest version (i.e. no updates are available from Conda)

The other thing I checked was the list of ogr drivers, created by the following code:

```py
import ogr
cnt = ogr.GetDriverCount()
formatsList = []  # Empty List
for i in range(cnt):
    driver = ogr.GetDriver(i)
    driverName = driver.GetName()
    if not driverName in formatsList:
        formatsList.append(driverName)
print(formatsList)
```

```
['ARCGEN', 'AVCBin', 'AVCE00', 'AeronavFAA', 'AmigoCloud', 'BNA', 'CAD', 'CSV', 'CSW', 'Carto', 'Cloudant', 'CouchDB', 'DB2ODBC', 'DGN', 'DXF', 'EDIGEO', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'ESRIJSON', 'ElasticSearch', 'GFT', 'GML', 'GMLAS', 'GPKG', 'GPSBabel', 'GPSTrackMaker', 'GPX', 'GeoJSON', 'GeoRSS', 'Geoconcept', 'Geomedia', 'HTF', 'HTTP', 'Idrisi', 'JML', 'KML', 'MBTiles', 'MSSQLSpatial', 'MVT', 'MapInfo File', 'Memory', 'NAS', 'ODBC', 'ODS', 'OGR_GMT', 'OGR_PDS', 'OGR_SDTS', 'OGR_VRT', 'OSM', 'OpenAir', 'OpenFileGDB', 'PCIDSK', 'PDF', 'PGDUMP', 'PGeo', 'PLSCENES', 'PostgreSQL', 'REC', 'S57', 'SEGUKOOA', 'SEGY', 'SQLite', 'SUA', 'SVG', 'SXF', 'Selafin', 'TIGER', 'TopoJSON', 'UK .NTF', 'VDV', 'VFK', 'WAsP', 'WFS', 'WFS3', 'Walk', 'XLS', 'XLSX', 'XPlane', 'netCDF']
```

And checking ogrinfo from the Anaconda prompt:

```
(my_env) C:\>ogrinfo --formats|findstr KML
  KML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
```

The printed list in Python does not contain LibKML. ogrinfo only returns the older KML driver, not LibKML
How can I get LibKML to work with OGR in python?

GDAL 3.0.1, Python 3.7.3, Windows 10

Comment: GDAL 3.0.1  Python 3.7.3

Comment: Works for me (GDAL 3.0.1 & Python 3.7.3 from conda-forge).  What's the output of `ogrinfo --formats|grep KML` (linux/macos) or `ogrinfo --formats|findstr KML` (windows)? And what's the output of `conda list`? Both run in the activated conda env. Please edit your question to add info, don't use comments.

Comment: I found this on geostack `from osgeo import ogr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in gdal 2.4.1 when installed using the wheel file from:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

download the relevant .whl file as needed and install using pip.